# How to count below extensions? by using c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to add a new asset detail by below C# code!
When I try to compile the code I get: "FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION WAS UNHANDLED".

How can I modify the program? - What is the reason for this exception?

---

**My Xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Assets>
  <Asset>
    <assetId></assetId>
    <assetName></assetName>
    <modelNo></modelNo>
    <price></price>
    <quantity></quantity>
  </Asset>
```

**My C# code:**

```
static List<Asset> Assets = new List<Asset>();

public static void AddSingleAsset() {
        Asset newAsset = new Asset();
        newAsset.assetId = Assets.Count + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Asset ID : {0}", newAsset.assetId);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the asset name");
        newAsset.assetName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Model number :");
        newAsset.modelNo = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Price :");
        newAsset.price = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity :");
        newAsset.quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Assets.Add(newAsset);
        string path = "Assets.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        doc.Elements("Assets").First().Add(new XElement("Asset", new XAttribute("assetId", newAsset.assetId),
            new XElement("assetName", newAsset.assetName),
            new XElement("modelNo", newAsset.modelNo),
            new XElement("price", newAsset.price),
            new XElement("quantity", newAsset.quantity)
       ));
            doc.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: `What is the reason for this exception?` I think it is clear. `FILE NOT FOUND`

Answer (score 2):

Hint: "File Not Found" should tell you to look for where you give your code the name of your file... But since you went through all the trouble of asking the question, try this:

1) check your path variable - change it to include the entire path of your file (@"c:\MyDirectory\Assets.xml")

2) Change

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("path");
```

To

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
```

and see what happens. Report back if you still have an error.

Comment: Hello
I modified what you say , my modified are,
  string path = (@"C:\Users\arunkumar.nagarajan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Employe Assets (linq to xmll)\Employe Assets (linq to xmll)\bin\Debug.Assets.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

this  will show below error message below

  string path = (@"C:\Users\arunkumar.nagarajan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Employe Assets (linq to xmll)\Employe Assets (linq to xmll)\bin\Debug.Assets.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

Comment: if I modified like below  this means 

  string path = ("Assets.xml");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

I get 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: That's a different message, so we've fixed "file not found." What is the error message and source?